# what does なってしもう mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, conversational, casual

> うち、あんたなしじゃあ生きていかれへん体になってしもうたんや。

My unsure translation: "House （うち）, I become（なってし**もう**？？） a body（体） who can't go on living（生きていかれへん） without you（あんたなし）".

whats going on with the なってしもう？ Is it a casual/conversational version of　なってしまう? Also what's that たん doing in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're translating a bit of Kansai dialect there. 
http://hougen.u-biq.org/osakaben.html

うち means "I" in this context, and yes, according to the page above, しまう becomes しもう with Kansai dialect. -ない also becomes -へん.

Your translation isn't too far off. I think it would roughly be, "I've become someone who can't live without you."

Comment: `しまう becomes しもう` --> た形（しまった⇒しもうた）て形（しまって⇒しもうて）以外では「しもう」にはなりませんけどね・・・　死んでしまう⇒死んでまう(×死んでしもう)　死んでしまいます⇒死んでまいます（×死んでしもいます）

Answer (score 5):

It's typical Kansai dialect speech.

- うち: female, casual first person pronoun (= あたし)
- あんた: second person pronoun (= あなた; not the same connotation as Tokyo あんた)
- いかれ(る): potential form of 行く "go", corresponding to 行ける in today's Tokyo
- へん: verb negation (= -ない)
- しもうた: past/perfect of しまう (= しまった)
- や: copula (= だ)

> うち、あんたなしじゃあ生きていかれへん体になってしもうたんや。
>   = あたし、あなたなしじゃ生きていけない体になってしまったんだ／しまったの。
>   = I've become such a woman who can't live [keep on living] without you.