# What "...しもーたん" could mean?

Tags: grammar, manga

I came up with this sentence while reading manga:

何であんなふうに育ってしもーたん。

**Context:** That's what the grandfather says after his grandson exits the house without telling anyone.

育って - I believe it's the te-form of the verb 育つ, which means (from Jisho.org):

1. to be raised (e.g. child); to be brought up; to grow (up)

I don't know what "しもーたん" is.
But from my research I gathered that しも could be [a grammatical element in archaic Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44663/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%97%E3%82%82) (a sort of intensifier similar to *nothing but, even, necessarily, etc*) and looking at Jisho.org, たん could be an honorifc but that doesn't make sense since there is no character called しも.

My second guess is that しもーたん could be a contraction for something else, which I cannot guess.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3299/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3688/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49157/7810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

しもーた is a variant of しもうた, which is a Kansai dialectal version of しまった used with an undesirable outcome. See the links posted by broccori. ん at the end of the sentence is [explanatory-の/ん used to seek clarification](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/). This type of sentence-end の commonly turns to ん in casual western speech (e.g., 好きなの? → 好きなん?).

> 何であんなふうに育ってしもーたん。
> = 何であんな風に育ってしまったの？
>
> Why did he grow up like that?